# Concatenate string in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I want to dynamically append the java script file name based on application culture name in mvc while giving reference of Java script file.

For e.g.

```
<script src="~/Clients/@tenant.ClientName/Backend/js/DateTimepickerLocalizetion/fr.js"></script>
```

Suppose my culture is `fr` and I want to append it dynamically in `src` tag, so my file name will be like `fr.js`.

I already have the culture name in `tenant` class, for which dependency is already injected.

But I am not able to append the file name with `.js` string.

So, how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have couple of choices here. You could construct script link in a code block and then use it in `src` like this:

```
@{
    var scriptLink = $"~/Clients/{tenant.ClientName}/Backend/js/DateTimepickerLocalizetion/{tenant.Culture}.js"
}

<script src="@scriptLink "></script>
```

If you want to keep it as 1 liner, you have to use braces to mark code blocks in markup. Like this:

```
<script src="~/Clients/@(tenant.ClientName)/Backend/js/DateTimepickerLocalizetion/@(tenant.Culture).js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome.. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

if you are using asp.net mvc, simply this will do the trick

```
<script src='@Scripts.Url(string.Format("~/Scripts/test.{0}.js", tenant.cultureName))'></script>
```